# Animation Nodes 2.0 Reload (F8) Not Working

Tags: animation-nodes

I've downloaded the Windows prebuilt AN 2.0 and installed on Blender 2.78C. AN loads fine on startup and seems to work, but I am doing additional development and when I reload with F8, the following AN error is generated.

Animation Nodes can't be reloaded.
Exception in module register(): 'E:\00visualNotes\workspace\visualNotes\addons\animation_nodes\__init__.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 349, in enable
    mod.register()
  File "E:\00visualNotes\workspace\visualNotes\addons\animation_nodes__init__.py", line 176, in register
    bpy.utils.register_module(**name**)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\modules\bpy\utils__init__.py", line 618, in register_module
    raise Exception("register_module(%r): defines no classes" % module)
Exception: register_module('animation_nodes'): defines no classes

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animation Nodes 2.0 does not support reloading.

This is because Python does not support reloading of extension modules, which AN has a lot of since it uses Cython.

So unfortunately you will have to disable AN completely during development or restart Blender every time you make a change.

Comment: Is it possible to build with the original python versions of the CPython modules and would this allow reloading?

Comment: Another thought... Is it possible for me to create two addons: AN2.0 and MyAddon which imports AN2. Disable reload on AN2 and reload MyAddon.